# Integration testing in .net core api 3.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-testhost

I am trying to implement integration testing for each API that i have developed in .Net core 3.1 and have followed   [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/test-aspnet-core-services-web-apps)      to create test cases for it.

Please find the below test class that i have created for my API.

[image]

But while executing i am getting error in this line `_server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
           .UseStartup<Startup>());`  which is as below :

[image: Error]

Am i missing anything here ?

Comment: In the future please post your code as text, not as a screenshot, so that it can be found by other people and so that copy/paste works. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error. its actually an issue in visual studio. please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52387048/9524580 will sort out the issue